# unbalanced dataset, anomalies have same distribution as normal data

Tags: python, data-science, anomaly-detection

I worked with a dataset which contains 2 classes (95%, 5%).

And the features of these 2 classes have almost the same distribution.

Question is: How can I classify these 2 classes and explain which principal the model uses to classify the test set?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually the distribution of features makes sense, but you have to make more detailed exploratory analysis than simple distribution of features. I suggest to have a look some 3D plots. You can have a look at some links about EDA:

https://www.kaggle.com/dejavu23/titanic-eda-to-ml-beginner

https://www.kaggle.com/dejavu23/house-prices-eda-to-ml-beginner

Regarding to classification models, I would suggest to have use `Decision Tree` based models, such as `Random Forest` or `Gradient Tree Boosting`. 
The idea behind `Decision Tree` is partition of feature space and making the same prediction for each part of it. You can plot Decision Trees, using some packages and it will help to understand principles behind the model. You can read more about all these models in the nice book:

http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/

Links to packages:

https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html

You can read about decision tree visualization:

https://medium.com/@rnbrown/creating-and-visualizing-decision-trees-with-python-f8e8fa394176

https://www.kaggle.com/willkoehrsen/visualize-a-decision-tree-w-python-scikit-learn